# parameter extraction from multiple parameter output in bash?

Tags: bash

Here's the bash script I am working on:

i/p: `ls *.py`
o/p: List of output files with `.py` extension

1.How do I know the number "n" of the `.py` files?
2.Then pump files one by one into the program to do further processing?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use an array:

```
# get the files
files=(*.py)

# list the files
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"

# count the files
n=${#files[@]}

# iterate over the files
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    someCommand "$file"
done
# or, if you want the index for some reason
for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do
    echo "$i: ${files[i]}"
done
```

bash arrays tutorial [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Comment: +1, this is the way to go. You may want to be explicit on the use of `shopt -s nullglob` to cover the case where no files exist